# Update field with where clause - firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to update the field "creator" to be an empty string in a document in react native with firestore but it does not work

```
firebase.firestore().collection("Users").where("creator","==",currentUserMail).where("user","==",childMail).limit(1).update({creator:""});
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: I have this error :
 [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: firebase.firestore().collection("Users").where("creator", "==", currentUserMail).where("user", "==", childMail).limit(1).update is not a function.

Comment: as per the docs, we can't use the update method of firestore when we use the limit feature. please refer to the rnfirebase docs for more details you have to find another way to update your desired values.

Comment: And can I use update with where clause?

Comment: You can only update a known document reference.  You need to get a query using where, to return all of the documents and then use `update` to update each of them individually.  If this is a bulk function, you will be better off doing this in Cloud Functions, in batches of <= 500

Comment: Not sure if you did, but when chaining `.where()` clauses like that, you need to add it as an index in the firebase console.

Comment: Firestore doesn't support update queries, where you pass a condition and an operation to the server in one go. You'll need to 1) execute a query, 2) loop over the results, 3) update each in turn.